# How will Ireland and Irish passports be affected by Brexit

Tags: passports, ireland, brexit

How Will Ireland and associated Irish passport be affected by Brexit?

Comment: This is either a very simple question (they won't be) or a very broad one, diving into a lot of history, economy, and geopolitics, depending on what you mean by "affected".

Comment: Given that it is currently far from clear if the UK and the EU will make any kind of deal (and if so what it might look like)regulating (some of) the things that might be affected, it's not really possible to answer this at the moment.

Comment: @Henrik the UK is going to continue Irish citizens' right to establish themselves in the UK whether there is a deal or not.  The deal, if there is one, will have only a modest effect on Irish citizens' rights.

Answer (score 2):

Ireland (commonly known as The Republic of Ireland, though the official name of the state is simply Ireland) is an independent country and an EU state. This status will not change. Ireland will remain a member state of the EU; Ireland issues its own passports and will continue to do so. Irish passports are EU passports.

Northern Ireland is part of the United Kingdom (full name: United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland), and will leave the EU along with the rest of the UK. The constituent countries of the UK do not issue their own passports, so there is no such thing as an NI passport. UK passports will cease to be EU passports, even if they still have the words *European Union* written on the front cover. New UK passports will no longer have that text (and will be blue).

Comment: There's a significant complication which you haven't mentioned here. The rules for acquiring Irish citizenship by birth apply to anyone born on the island of Ireland, including Northern Ireland. While Northern Ireland doesn't issue its own passports, the majority of residents of Northern Ireland are entitled to an Irish passport.

Comment: @MJeffreys, Actually, they are entitled to Irish nationality, which in turn would entitle them to an Irish passport, but only if they acquire that nationality first. A British citizen of Belfast can't just request an Irish passport just because.

Comment: @DiegoSánchez OK, this is a fair distinction, but my point is that the answer missed out this significant anomaly to Irish citizenship law.

Comment: @MJeffryes but that's not changing, so mentioning it does not particularly help to answer the question.

Comment: @phoog None of it is changing, so by that argument the whole answer is unhelpful.

Comment: @MJeffryes Irish citizens' ability to travel to the UK with non-Irish, non-British family members is changing.

Comment: @phoog that’s not mentioned at all in the answer unless I’m being dense.